# Event binding for a dynamically generated element within a dynamically generated element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use 'click' on a dynamically generated DOM. I know that I can just use live or on, however my dynamically generated content is within multiple dynamically generated pieces of content and live/on no longer works.

So my code looks something like this but with more elements before El_b:

```
El_a = document.createElement("li");
El_b = document.createElement("a");
El_b.id = "myEl";
El_a.appendChild(El_b);
```

Is there a way to make this work?

PS: I've also tried the livequery jQuery plugin.

Comment: DOM means Document Object Model. Sometimes, DOM is colloquially used to mean an *instance* of the Document Object Model. But in either case, calling individual elements "DOMs" is totally incorrect. They are **elements** in a *single* DOM. Don't call them DOMs, this is confusing and misleads people into thinking you are referring to multiple documents. Please update your question to remove references to "DOMs".

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should use it for everything, including create new elements, setting attributes and appending elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code that is creating the new elements is not mine.

Comment: Please provide a sample page at jsfiddle.net so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as delegation is concerned, you always have at least one static DOM element available to you, which is the `document`. If you can't find a closer element to delegate to, delegate to this.

However, delegation seems to be unnecessary here. The entire process of creating your elements and attaching listeners could be condensed to:

```
var a = $("<li/>").append($("<a/>").attr("id", "myElement")).click(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

If, as you say, you cannot change the object creation, you can still select it by its ID and attach the listener:

```
$('#myElement').click(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Also, those are *document fragments*, not documents proper, and certainly not DOMs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the object creation is not in my code. Is there any way to directly bind 'click' to the element so that I can use it with $("#myName").click ?

Comment: The problem I'm having though is that using $('#myElement').click won't work if the element is created with document.createElement(). It usually works if I have $('#myElement').on('click',blah) but it's not working in this case if the element being created has been appended to another

Comment: @user1811367 It will still work regardless of how you created it, provided you have actually added it to the document. Right now you're making two elements and adding one to the other, but neither of them are in the document yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a function on the click event on El_b, you can just do this :

```
$(El_b).click(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

But you can use `on` i think. Even if you create multiple DOM elements. You can use the `document` or the `body`. Example :

```
$('body').on('click', 'li a.my_class', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this if I don't know that the hierarchy is body>li>a? So all I have is body>?????>a.

Comment: use a css class. And all you have to do is 'a.my_class'